# jquery modal form triggered twice (random behaviour)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am using Dropzone.js to upload image to my site. Everything works fine when i upload the images. The problem happens when i try to download the images. It has a strange behaviour because sometimes it happens and some not. When i click on the "trash" icon to delete the image, a modal form shows and i can choose if delete or not the image. The problem is that sometimes, when i choose to delete the image pressing the cancel button, two images are being delete and two modal form shows up (one after the other) and when this happens the page is locked. I cannot figure out if the problem is in the jquery code or in the html markup.. may you help me please?

this is the html code ( part of a php function):

```
$this->html .= "<div class='row'>";
foreach($this->rows as $this->row) {
    $this->html .= "  <div class='col-md-2 col-thumbnail'>";
    $this->html .= "    <div class='card'>";
    $this->html .= "        <img class='card-img-top' src='../" . $this->row['foto'] . "'" . "alt=''>";
    $this->html .= "         <div class='card-body'>";
    $this->html .= "            <a href='#' class='a_trash' rel='" . $this->row['id'] . "'" . ">" . "<i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x position' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
    $this->html .= "         </div> <!-- end card body -->";
    $this->html .= "    </div> <!-- end card -->";
    $this->html .= "   </div> <!-- end col-md-3 -->";
    }
$html .= "</div>";
```

This is,instead, the jquery code that trigger the modal form (bootstrap 5):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.a_trash', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id =  $(this).attr('rel');
  var thisObject = $(this).closest();
  var data_1 = 'id=' + id;
  $('#mdl-avviso').modal('show');
  $("#del").on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: data_1,
      url: "php/del-img.php"
      })
    .done(function() {
      $('#mdl-avviso').modal('toggle');
      $(thisObject).fadeOut(300,function() {
        $(thisObject).remove();
        });
      }); // END DONE FUNCTION
    }); // END IF CONFIRM
  }); // END DOCUMENT ON CLICK
}); // END DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION
```

and this is the modal:

```
    <!-- MODAL START HERE -->

        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mdl-avviso">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><b><u>My Project</u></b></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                Would you like to delete the image, are you sure?
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="del" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancella</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-bg-v" id="dismiss" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Annulla</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

   <!-- MODAL END HERE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

the right code is this one:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').unbind('click').on('click', '.a_trash', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).closest(".a_trash").attr('rel');
      var item = $(this).parent().parent();
      $('#mdl-avviso').modal('show');
      $('#del').unbind('click').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();       
          $.ajax({
            url: 'php/del-img.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(data) {
              $(item).fadeOut(300,function() {
                $(item).remove();
                });
            }
          });
      });
    });
  });
```